# How to join 3 and more tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me in joining 3 and more tables in SQL with simple syntax. I was not able to find the exact syntax for this.

Comment: There you go http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Hi Mureinik, I tried with these links.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191430%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/435694/Understanding-Table-Joins-using-SQL#_articleTop

Comment: Be more concrete. Give us an example SQL not the pages you visited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have table 1, table 2 and table 3. Let´s create a simple example.

table 1: employees: id, **department_id**, first_name, last_name, salary...

table 2: departments: id, **location_id**, department_name...

table 3: locations: id, city...

department_id and location_id are foreign keys. Employees have a department_id and Departments have a location_id. You need this foreign keys in order to JOIN different tables.

Then you can use this query to join the tables:

```
SELECT first_name, salary, department_name, city
FROM departments JOIN employees USING (department_id)
JOIN locations USING (location_id)
GROUP BY first_name, salary, department_name, city;
```

If you want to learn more about different kind of joins I found a good explanation [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/448080/4438391)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that there are three tables x,y,z:

```
Table x - id,Column1
Table y - id,Column2
Table z - id, Column3
```

Try the script below:

```
select x.column1,y.column2,z.column3 from x
inner join y on x.id = y.id
inner join z on x.id = z.id
```